# Delete all texts between two texts

Tags: messages, ios, iphone

A good friend of mine recently spammed my phone with close to a thousand messages... It's technically my fault since I was telling him that he should learn a scripting language. Ooops.

Anyway, is there a way that I can "group delete" text messages (perhaps with an app) instead of individually checking each message or deleting all of them?

Comment: did you try to remove the friend

Comment: Whats wrong with delete the conversation?

Comment: @soulshined there were some texts worthwhile saving for reference.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin then your out of luck. No way to group delete other than what your doing. You should just take a screen shot of the messages you want for reference, otherwise it will be a long week for you

Comment: To clarify, no 3rd party app is going to have access to your OS-shipped messages. That should be a privacy red flag to anyone and everyone